# Why Number.isFinite dont have type guard?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can someone ask me why `Number.isFinite` dont have type guard like `number is number`?

THis example provides an error `Object is possibly 'undefined'`

```
function inc (n?: number) {
  return Number.isFinite(n) ? n + 1 : 1;
}
```

Playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDSiAUYD8AuRYQC2ARgKYBOAlIgN4BQiiZJUIZSAcoaWQHQwDOAMRQwoJDFUx5EAakQBGRLnkBuWgF8gA

Comment: This is when writing TS wastes your time. Everyone is chasing type checking instead of actually getting stuff done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First some background. On first glance, this seems to be related to the difference in JavaScript between

```
isFinite
```

which will first convert its argument to number and

```
Number.isFinite
```

which happily accepts all arguments, regardless of type, and simply returns `true` only for finite numbers (with no implicit conversions). In TypeScript these have signatures

```
function isFinite(number: number): boolean

(method) NumberConstructor.isFinite(number: unknown): boolean
```

In the second method, the parameter type is `unknown` instead of `number`. The reason is that in JavaScript, `Number.isFinite` happy returns `false` for non-numbers (whereas `isFinite` coerces first).

```
> Number.isFinite(false)
false
> isFinite(false)
true
> Number.isFinite(Symbol(2))
false
> isFinite(Symbol(2))
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a number at isFinite (<anonymous>)
```

Now since `Number.isFinite` *is already expected to accept all arguments from any type* and return `false` no matter how wacky the arguments, it makes sense for this behavior to be preserved in TypeScript. Hence the parameter type properly is `unknown`. For the global `isFinite` which is intended to work only on numbers (and does the coercion that TypeScript helps us avoid), it makes sense to restrict the parameter to being a `number`.

But as your question rightly asks, why, given that `Number.isFinite` will accept any arguments and return `true` only for numbers, why can't it be a type guard? The reason is that it returns true for *some*, but not *all* numbers! Let's try at least to write our own guard:

```
function numberIsFinite(n: any): n is number {
    return Number.isFinite(n)
}
```

and these make sense:

```
console.log(numberIsFinite(20)) // true
console.log(numberIsFinite(Number.MAX_VALUE)) // true
console.log(numberIsFinite(undefined)) // false
console.log(numberIsFinite("still ok")) // false
```

But here is where things go wrong-ish:

```
console.log(numberIsFinite(Infinity)) // false but uh-oh
console.log(numberIsFinite(NaN)) // false but uh-oh
```

Now it's true that with this type guard that

```
const x: number|string = 3
if (numberIsFinite(x)) {
  console.log(`A number whose type is ${typeof(x)}`)
} else {
  console.log(`A string whose type is ${typeof(x)}`)
}
```

will print

```
"A number whose type is number"
```

so far so good but:

```
const x: number|string = Infinity
if (numberIsFinite(x)) {
  console.log(`A number whose type is ${typeof(x)}`)
} else {
  console.log(`A string whose type is ${typeof(x)}`)
}
```

will print

```
"A string whose type is number"
```

And this is silly.

If there was a dependent type in TS called "finite number" then (and perhaps only then) would making `Number.isFinite` a type guard make sense.

Credit to @VLAZ, whose answer this explanation is based on. I added the second part to my original answer after reading theirs.

Comment: Very well said. I learned quite a bit through this, thank you!

Comment: This is useful information but OP is asking why `Number.isFinite()` is not a type guard. Presumably if you do `if (Number.isFinite(x)) x += 2;` that's always going to be correct. There are no instances where `Number.isFinite` will return `true` but the parameter is not a number type.

Comment: @RayToal the reason is basically that with `Number.isFinite()` returning `false`, the value can still be a number. The first draft of my answer was when I somehow read `isFinite` multiple times and yet somehow thought of it as `isInteger`. Had to re-write it with a more apt example for non-finite values.

Comment: I saw your answer temporarily deleted and rewritten, nice work. I'm updating my answer too for posterity, but yours should be accepted.

Answer (score 7):

`Number.isFinite()` is not a type guard because it can lead to weird and wrong behaviour in edge cases.

`Number.isFinite(4)` -> `true` and the value is a number. That's fine.
`Number.isFinite("apple")` -> `false` and the value is not a number. That's fine.
`Number.isFinite(Infinity)` -> `false` but the value is ***not*** not a number. That's not good.

Some things in JavaScript are of type `number` but are not finite. These are the values `Infinity`, `-Infinity` and `NaN`. Yes, it stands for "not a number" but it's of type number. It's confusing but makes sense.<sup>1</sup>

In most cases, we don't care about these non-finite values.

However, as they are still numbers, they are valid in mathematical operations. The concept of infinity is also mathematical and sometimes can be useful.

Discarding these values leads to sometimes wrong code. Let's assume that `Number.isFinite()` was declared as a type guard. Then consider this code:

```
function atLeast(minValue: string | number, x: number): boolean {
    const min: number = Number.isFinite(x)
        ? minValue
        : Number(minValue.replace(/\D/g, "")); //convert
    
    return num >= min;
}
```

```
atLeast(2, 42);            //true
atLeast("$3.50", 42);      //true
atLeast(-Infinity, 42);    //error
```

This would be valid code. Wrong logic and a bit weird but it's here to just illustrate a point. Still, a more realistic usage might be:

```
let dynamicMinimum = -Infinity; //allow all
/* ... */
someArray.filter(x => atLeast(dynamicMinimum, x));
```

The code in the function is accepted by TypeScript *and* when `Number.isFinite()` returns `false` type narrowing would cause `minValue` would not be considered a number and only allowed to be treated as a string by the compiler.

While the example here is contrived and not too hard to figure out it's wrong, you can easily get into a real world situation where you accidentally narrow a value out of being a number when it's still a number. This would be why `Number.isFinite()` is not a type guard - it can erroneously assert something about a type that is misleading.

---

<sup>1</sup> Here is what I hope is an intuitive explanation why `NaN` is a number type. In JavaScript values can be changed and some mathematical operations *need* a number to work with, otherwise they make no sense. But not everything converts to a number. So when you convert a value to a number, you need to somehow signify that it cannot be converted. This is where `NaN` comes in.

Since the contextual information for what `NaN` was before conversion, you cannot definitely say it's equal to anything, hence why `NaN == NaN` is `false`. An equivalent code might be `Number("apple") == Number("orange")` - the two values are clearly not equal before the conversion.

Comment: This is a great answer. As an aside, "not everything can be converted to a number" that's a good point, and it's not just `NaN` that comes into play here. Attempting to convert a Symbol into a number throws a `TypeError`.

Comment: @RayToal yeah...symbols are weird. Not necessarily because they are wrong, they just don't work a lot like everything else does. Which is pretty much correct - using symbols for some operations goes beyond meaningless `"apple" * "orange"` is a meaningless operation - syntactically valid but garbage input leading to garbage output. With symbols, mathematical operations are a hard mistake. Not just garbage input - it's invalid. This is *good* but then leads to strangeness with the existing way of handling things. BigInt also works similarly `2n * 4` leads to an error.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no way to return a value combined with some guard conditions in typescript. What you can do is
a) Add an additional check for not undefined values (but I think that in your case you probably will not need Number.isFinite anymore)

```
function inc (n?: number) {
    return typeof n === "number" && Number.isFinite(n) ? n + 1 : 1;
}
```

b) or write your own isFiniteNumber guard.

Comment: a) but Number.isFinite already clearly defines that the number is passed
b) hmm...

Comment: Why not do `Number.isFinite(n) ? n! + 1 : 1`

Comment: Improved the first check to accept 0 values

Comment: @HaoWu it works but it's more of a crutch

Comment: > a) but Number.isFinite already clearly defines that the number is transmitted
yes, but it is not a guard function (typing is different). That is why TypeScript does not understand that "n" is defined in that branch.